# How to calculate an average of TIMESTAMP column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, timestamp

I have a column called timestamp

I want to know the average timestamp from all the entries

this is because I need to know in which time is where the user do some actions in my app

The format of each timestamp entries are this one

```
2020-07-13 00:01:12.616 UTC
```

I cant just use

```
SELECT AVG(timestamp) from my_table
```

Because AVG is just for certain types

How can I calculate the average time ?

Comment: BigQuery or MySQL? Please tag only the one database that you are using.

Comment: What's an average timestamp? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @GMB BigQuery by google

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert to seconds (or milliseconds or microseconds) and back to a timestamp:

```
select timestamp_seconds(cast(avg(unix_seconds(timestamp)) as int64))
from my_table
```

Comment: got the followin No matching signature for function TIMESTAMP_SECONDS for argument types: FLOAT64. Supported signature: TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(INT64) at [1:8]

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

I assume you want to know avg time of the day of user's' activity  or something like this - per your statement  `I need to know in which time is where the user do some actions in my app`

```
#standardSQL
SELECT TIMESTAMP_ADD(ts, INTERVAL avg_value MILLISECOND) 
FROM (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, DAY) ts, CAST(AVG(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ts, TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, DAY), MILLISECOND)) AS INT64) avg_value
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, DAY)
)
```

you can test, play with above using dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-07-13 00:01:12.616 UTC' ts UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-07-13 00:01:14.616 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-07-13 00:01:15.616 UTC' 
)
SELECT TIMESTAMP_ADD(ts, INTERVAL avg_value MILLISECOND) 
FROM (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, DAY) ts, CAST(AVG(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ts, TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, DAY), MILLISECOND)) AS INT64) avg_value
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, DAY)
)
```

with output

```
Row f0_  
1   2020-07-13 00:01:14.283 UTC
```